# Integration using SciPy quad function (Definite Integrals)

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I have been trying to integrate 2x dx from 3 to 4 using SciPy but it is returning an incorrect value.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def g(x):
  return (2*(x**2))/2

quad(g,3,4)
```

The result returned should be 7, but I am getting result as 12.3333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're providing the antiderivative of the function you intend to integrate, but `scipy.integrate.quad()` expects the the function by itself.

In other words, if you want to integrate 2*x, then you should provide 2*x.

However, since you do have the antiderivative, you don't need `quad()` at all. You can just evaluate your antiderivative at the beginning and end of your integral's bounds. The `quad()` function is most useful when the integral has no known analytic solution.

Here is an example of how to solve this integral, with and without `quad()`.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad


def g(x):
    return 2 * x


def g_integral(x):
    return (2 * (x**2))/2


print("Integral via numeric integration", quad(g, 3, 4))
print("Integral via analytic solution", g_integral(4) - g_integral(3))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and you made me understand the concept